Как сделать чтение-запись настроек в(на) appsettings.json приложения?
Как сделать чтение-запись настроек в(на) appsettings.json приложения?
Проект: https://github.com/Dev65432/AppSettingsQ
Сейчас пробую так(не работает):
private async Task SaveSettingsExecuted()
        {
            _configuration["PathToImg"] = PathToImg;

            var fgfg = _configuration["PathToImg"];


            // Сохранение изменений в файл appsettings.json
            IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot = (IConfigurationRoot)_configuration;
            configurationRoot.Reload(); 

            IsButtonEnabled = false;
        }

Код
 public class Deals2ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        IConfiguration _configuration;
        private IRepository<Deal> _dealsRepository;        
        private IRepository<Picture> _pictureRepository;

        public Deals2ViewModel(IConfiguration configuration,
                               IRepository<Deal> DealsRepository,                               
                               IRepository<Picture> pictureRepository)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _dealsRepository = DealsRepository;            
            _pictureRepository = pictureRepository;            
        }

#region  Command OpenAppSettingsCommand - Отобразить окно настроек
        private ICommand _openAppSettingsCommand;

        public ICommand OpenAppSettingsCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _openAppSettingsCommand ??
                    (_openAppSettingsCommand = new RelayCommand(() => OnOpenAppSettingsExecuted()));
            }
        }

        private async Task OnOpenAppSettingsExecuted()
        {
            AppSettingsViewModel appSettingsViewModel = new AppSettingsViewModel(_configuration);

            AppSettingsWindow appSettingsWindow = new AppSettingsWindow();
            appSettingsWindow.DataContext = appSettingsViewModel;
            appSettingsWindow.Show();
        }

        #endregion





<DockPanel>
        <GroupBox Header="Настройки приложения">
            <Grid Margin="3">
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Grid.Column" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,2,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Grid.Column" Value="1">
                                <!--<Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0,0,0"/>-->
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,20,20,20"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>

                </Grid.Resources>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Путь к папке с картинками: "/>
                <TextBox   Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  Text="{Binding PathToImg,
                                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>


                <Button Content="Сохранить" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="100"         
                        Command="{Binding SaveSettingsCommand}"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsButtonEnabled}"
                        Background="{Binding ButtonColor}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
    </DockPanel>




 public class AppSettingsViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        IConfiguration _configuration;

        public AppSettingsViewModel(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            
            StartUp();
        }

        public void StartUp()
        {
            PathToImg = _configuration["PathToImg"];
            
            IsButtonEnabled = false;
        }

        private string _pathToImg;

        public string PathToImg
        {
            get 
            {
                // _pathToFastStoneExe = _configuration["FastStonePath"];
                
                return _pathToImg; 
            }
            set 
            {

                _pathToImg = value;                
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PathToImg));

                UpdateButtonState();
            }
        }


        #region Кнопка Сохранить
        // private Brush _buttonColor = Brushes.Gray;
        private Brush _buttonColor;
        public Brush ButtonColor
        {
            get { return _buttonColor; }
            set
            {
                _buttonColor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ButtonColor));
            }
        }

        private bool _isButtonEnabled = false;

        public bool IsButtonEnabled
        {
            get { return _isButtonEnabled; }
            set
            {
                _isButtonEnabled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsButtonEnabled));
            }
        }
        
        private void UpdateButtonState()
        {
            IsButtonEnabled = true;
            ButtonColor = Brushes.Red;
            // ButtonColor = IsButtonEnabled ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.Gray;
            // ButtonColor = IsButtonEnabled ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.Gray;
        }

        #endregion

        #region  Command SaveSettingsCommand - Команда загрузки данных из репозитория
        /// <summary>Отобразить представление статистики</summary>
        private ICommand _SaveSettingsCommand;

        public ICommand SaveSettingsCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _SaveSettingsCommand ??
                    (_SaveSettingsCommand = new RelayCommand(() => SaveSettingsExecuted()));
            }
        }

        private async Task SaveSettingsExecuted()
        {
            _configuration["PathToImg"] = PathToImg;

            var fgfg = _configuration["PathToImg"];


            // Сохранение изменений в файл appsettings.json
            IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot = (IConfigurationRoot)_configuration;
            configurationRoot.Reload(); 

            IsButtonEnabled = false;
        }

        #endregion
    }

appsettings.json
{
  "Database": {
    "Type": "SQLite",
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "MSSQL": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=AppsettingsWpf.db;Integrated Security=True",
      "SQLite": "Data Source=Market.db"
    }
  },
  "PathToImg": "AppFiles\\Imgs\\"
}

**Program.cs
class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var app = new App();
            app.InitializeComponent();
            app.Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host
           .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .ConfigureServices(App.ConfigureServices)
           .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
           {
               config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
           })                    
            ;
       
    }

App.xaml.cs
public partial class App : Application
    {

        private static IHost __Host;

        public static IHost Host => __Host
            ??= Program.CreateHostBuilder(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()).Build();

        public static IServiceProvider Services => Host.Services;

        internal static void ConfigureServices(HostBuilderContext host, 
                                         IServiceCollection services) => 
            services
               .AddDatabase(host.Configuration.GetSection("Database"))
               .AddRepositoriesInDB()
              //.AddServices()
              .AddViewModels()
        ;

        protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            // IsDesignTime = false;

            var host = Host;

            using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
                scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbInitializer>()
                .InitializeAsync().Wait();

            base.OnStartup(e);
            await host.StartAsync();
        }

        protected override async void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
        {
            using var host = Host;
            base.OnExit(e);
            await host.StopAsync();
        }
    }


Стандартный конфигуратор не имеет такой возможности. То, что вы задаете reloadOnChange: true или вызываете Reload();, означает "чтение", то есть, вы просите конфигуратор повторно загрузить данные из JSON файла, если тот был изменен, это ни как не влияет на запись в файл JSON при изменении данных в конфигураторе. Для того, чтобы конфигуратор сохранял данные при изменении, вам надо делать своего провайдера, ну или свой IOptions.

Запись параметров в appsettings.json не рекомендована. Лучше используйте другой способ для сохранения настроек. По этой причине у C# по дефолту не реализована такая возможность.
